# I accepted all answer

Tags: support, accepted-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do when getting “Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-thi)
>   [My account is banned, how can I ask questions again?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111189/my-account-is-banned-how-can-i-ask-questions-again)

I didn't accept answers in all my question.
because I didn't know.

But Now I know.

So I accepted the answer in all my question.

will I come back??

Comment: I assume you have some sort of ban/block? That wouldn't be related to you not accepting answers. Do you see the message "We are not accepting any more questions from this account?", or are you talking about something else?

Comment: I would strongly suggest you ***edit to improve*** the quality of your questions to avoid downvotes.  The more downvotes and deleted questions you have, the more likely you get blocked by the system.

Comment: Soon you will be banned here on Meta as well.

Answer (score 5):

From what I gather from your question [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111189/my-account-is-banned-how-can-i-ask-questions-again), you were question banned because you deleted too many, not because you didn't accept answers. I am not a moderator, but I don't think improving your acceptance rate will necessarily result in an unban. I suggest reading your other question and it's answers more carefully.

Comment: That, and many of the questions were poorly asked, so they racked up a lot of downvotes. The questions need to be fixed first, and accepting answers will have nothing to do with the automated question asking ban.